# Delete 100 lines from vi editor using single command

Tags: command-line, vi, command

I am using Ubuntu and trying to delete all 100 lines from `vi` editor but I got interview question of doing this in one command.

Comment: Not a VI solution, but from the command line: `echo -n > <file>` removes all lines from a file (actually just overwrites the file with "").

Comment: @Der No need to use `echo` at all for that; `> $file` works just fine.

Comment: What kind of company is that, asking questions about `vi` in an interview?

Comment: This question is easily answered with a rudimentary knowledge of vi. On a computer with vim installed (on Ubuntu I'd recommend the `vim-gtk` package, since that gives you access to the xclipboard within vim), type `vimtutor` at the command line (not within vim) to get an interactive tutorial of the basics. It shouldn't take more than half an hour, and it's the best starter's guide to using vi/vim that you're likely to find.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I could imagine it coming up in an interview if the applicant had either mentioned prior experience with `vi` (verbally or by resumé) or if the question were prefaced with, "Okay, as a sysadmin you must know something of command line editors, right?  You've used `vi`?"

Answer (score 70):

In normal mode, do

```
100dd
```

`dd` deletes the current line.  Prefacing that command with `100` causes it to repeat 100 times.

If there are fewer than 100 lines in the file starting from the current line, depending on the `vi` implementation, it will either fail to delete any or delete as many as there are. In the case of `vim`, that depends on whether the `cp` aka `compatible` option is on or not.

Comment: wrong anwser it is only deleting current line

Comment: I want to delete 100 lines using one command at a one time

Comment: `100dd` is the correct answer. I wonder what you're doing.

Comment: @mayurMehta don't know which company is asking questions like this, and don't know what they are expecting as the answer. But any novice VI user will know that 100dd is the correct answer.

Comment: Making the assumption that the file is exactly 100 lines long, and the cursor is on line 1, this is the correct answer.  If the cursor is on line 2, then no action will happen if you press 100dd.  So a novice vim user, as @Munim indicates may indeed think that this is the correct answer, but they would be correct only in a very specific case.  And this would not work from the command line.  Unless of course, you record the command and read it in later `vim -s 100dd_command file.txt`

Comment: @vgoff If the cursor is on line 2, it will delete lines 2 to 101. If there are fewer than 100 lines in the file, it will delete up to the end of the file. The question asked for a vi command, not a shell command.

Comment: Actually if it is less than 100 lines in the file, it won't do anything.  Check it by opening up vim (perhaps without any plugins that you have) and see.  It is easy to check. And yes, though I mentioned it only because they tagged it as 'commmand line' which implies a command from the command line.

Comment: @vgoff I don't know.. If they are not looking for a general solution to test your basic vim skills, then it is just a trick question to stump interviewees. I'd say 100dd is the answer. If the interviewer asks "What happens if the file has less than 100 lines from the current cursor?", I'd answer: "The command deletes what it can from the current cursor." That is perfectly reasonable. Unless the interviewer clarifies, why would the cursor not be on the first line? I hate trick questions like these.

Comment: But it won't perform the operation if there are less than 100 lines.  I guess the answer that 'it deletes what it can' is reasonable, except that it is wrong. @suspectus I think has the best answer, it relies on no position, so will always work, regardless of initial cursor location.  If the 'entire file' needs to be cleared of lines, that will always do so. I was kind of disappointed that the OP did not give the answer they gave, and the supplied (if any) solution the interviewer gave.

Comment: @vgoff, I checked.  It *does* perform the operation if there are less than 100 lines.  What version of `vi` are you using?

Comment: Since the answer was written more than two years ago, I am not sure the version I am using now would answer the intended question.  Analyze it, though, the 'repeats 100 times' is not accurate if there are less than 100 lines to delete.  Otherwise you would find that the line you are on is gone, you would then be on the last line, and the last line would then be gone, and then it would repeat again until there are no lines in the file.  This simply does not happen.

Answer (score 49):

1. delete 100 lines forward from (including) the current one

   - repeat dd (delete current line) 100 times:

     ```
     100dd
     ```
   - delete from current line to 99 lines forward

     ```
     d99j
     ```
2. delete 100 lines backwards from (including) the current one

   ```
   d99k
   ```
3. delete lines in a specific range by line number

   ```
   :1,100d
   ```
4. delete lines in a range beginning with the current line

   ```
   :.,.+99d
   ```

etc. etc.

Comment: number 4 will delete current line (0) until 101th (0+100) lines, hence 101 lines instead of the asked 100. try `:.,+99d`

Comment: 100dd didn't work for me either - but #4 above works fine for me in VI under Solaris 10.

Answer (score 7):

If ***all*** lines in the file are to be deleted, this vi command specifies the range of deletion:

```
:1,$d
```

`1` denotes the first line and 
`$` denotes the last line

Comment: or `:%d`  (in ":" context, ":%..." is shortcut for ":1,$...")

Comment: also nice: `d` `G` keys  &rarr; kill all content from actual [e.g. top line] to bottom line

Answer (score 4):

You want to delete all the lines in a file? Open the file with `vi`. While at the beginning of the first line -- the default location of the cursor when you just open the file -- press <kbd>Esc</kbd> followed by <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>.

Just to note, the action `d` indicates delete, and `G` indicates the last line of the file. So, while at any line you press <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, it deletes all the line starting from the current line till the last one.

If you know which consecutive lines to delete -- say, from line 101 to 200 -- type in the following key sequences:
<kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>,</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>.

Comment: No need to press escape if you have just opened the file and are at the beginning of the file.  You are automatically (by default) in normal mode.

Answer (score 3):

No matter where are you are in the file, you can do `ggdG`

`:%d` would do better in less key presses.  Well, counting the `shift` and `enter` keys, actually two more key presses than the above.

Doing something like `100dd` would only delete *up to* 100 lines from where you are, and that may not delete all lines from the file, depending on your current line position.

Answer (score 0):

Esc n dd. 
n is the number of lines to delete from and including the current line. 
Press "Esc" button, then "n" and then "dd".
[To better your understanding](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~hanson/UNIX/UnixDictionary.html)

Comment: What is the need of escape here

Comment: This answer is identical to the accepted answer.

Comment: Escape is just in case you are in insert mode.